# Clear all controls inside of a popup panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to clear  all the controls inside of a popup panel (modalPopupExtender), but my code doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> EnumerateControlsRecursive(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            yield return child;
            foreach (Control descendant in EnumerateControlsRecursive(child))
                yield return descendant;
        }
    }

      public void clearInputs(Panel cph)
      {
        foreach (Control c in EnumerateControlsRecursive(cph))
          {
              if (c is TextBox)
                  ((TextBox)c).Text = String.Empty;
              else if (c is DropDownList)
                  ((DropDownList)c).ClearSelection();
                  else if (c is CheckBox)
                  ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
          }
      }
```

I call clearInputs on button click.

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: When you debug, how does it fail?  Is `clearInputs` called?  When you step through it in the debugger, does it find the controls you expect it to find?  Is it setting their properties as you expect?  Is something else also setting those properties to have values afterward?  Where specifically does the problem occur?

Comment: what exactly is the unexpected behavior?

Comment: clearInput is called yes, and I don't get any errors or something in debugger, I just don't get the textboxes,dropdownlists and checkboxes cleared.